# Get value from echo different file php using ajax and change the value to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Sorry if this question was already been asked before, but i tried to find reference for my issue but still not found and can't implemented. I'm new for javascript and ajax programming. hope you can help and explain to me how its works.

I have 2 php file :

File 1 : total_output.php

```
<?php 

$total_output = 40;

echo $total_output;

?>
```

file 2 : ajax_call.php

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
         url: 'total_output.php',
         success: function(data) {
         alert(data);
        }
    });     
 });
</script>
```

Is it possible value ***40*** from **alert(data);**  change to php variable and then echo in ajax_call.php? how i can do it?

Appreciate your help and explanation.. Thanks..

Comment: `Is it possible value 40 from alert(data); change to php variable` No, it's not. The PHP code runs on the server. The AJAX request is JS code that runs on the client, a *long* time after the PHP has finished execution. I'm confused as to why you'd need this, as the whole point of AJAX is to get data in to JS *from* PHP. If you need the value to be in PHP, use it in the `total_output.php` file.

Comment: If you mean insert the 40 into the page somewhere, instead of putting inside "alert" then yes of course you can do that - take a tutorial in using JavaScript to change your page contents.